# What do the playing cards do in the binding of isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I have found playing cards (NOT tarot cards) e.g. the two of clubs. I am unsure of their use and I am wondering if they even **have** a use. I know what the ace of spades does, but that's about it.

Comment: The Binding of Issac Wiki has pages for every card, iteam etc. detailing there use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two of Clubs: Doubles your bombs, if you have no bombs it will give you 2 bombs.

The two of Diamonds: Will double your coins or give you 2 if you have none.

The two of Spades: Will double your keys or give you 2 if you have none.

The two of Heats: Doubles Isaacs number of hearts.

There are extra cards that do come from the DLC

Ace of Clubs: Turns all pickups and chests into bombs

Ace of Diamonds: Turns all pickups and chests into coins

Ace of Spades: Turns all pickups and chests into keys.

Ace of Hearts: Turns all pickups and chests into random heart pickups.

Joker: Teleport you to the devil or angel room.